# An efficient algorithm to find a shortest cycle including a specific vertex

Tags: algorithms, graphs, search-algorithms

We wish to find shortest cycle (if any cycle exists) that includes a special vertex $v$.

We know if we run DFS on an undirected graph, back edges show us that there exists at least one cycle.

[This answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847463/finding-length-of-shortest-cycle-in-undirected-graph) explains why neither BFS or DFS work. However, I still think that DFS could be helpful in finding a minimun such cycle. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: That seems to be explained in the SO post as well. I don't see what your question is now. Community votes, please: unclear?

Comment: @Shaull I tried hard to solve it  with DFS It might be cause of that I didn't see how BFS works well. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You can find the shortest cycle that contains $v$ by running BFS from $v$, and stopping at the first time that $v$ is reached again (or if BFS terminated without reaching $v$).

An important property of BFS is that if it runs from vertex $v$, then every vertex $s$, when it is first reached, then the path that was found from $v$ to $s$ is minimal. Thus, reaching $v$ from $v$ with BFS finds the shortest path from $v$ to itself, namely the shortest cycle that contains $v$.

Comment: I think your algorithm only works when the underlying graph is directed

Comment: @Null_Space - an undirected graph is a special case of a directed graph (with the edge relation is symmetric). Also, an undirected graph has a cycle iff it has an edge, because you can go back and forth.

Answer (score -1):

How can you reach from v to v using bfs? And bfs gives wrong ans for the graph->
1 2
2 3
2 4
3 4
given that special vertex is 1.
Here BFS will tell that there is a cycle but that cycle does not includes special vertex 1.